# To do check list in Android List view?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-edittext

I am building a application with to do checklist in it. In this is want to have a simple list view but with editable Edit text in it. I am able to populate the list with the initial values. How ever when i enter text into the edit text, somewhere in between the getview gets called from the adapter and the list view refreshes itself. I tried a round about where i keep updating the data source as and when I am typing in the edit text. Now the value is saved even after refresh. But the problem is that I keep entering the text and in between the list refreshes and i loose the focus from the edit text. Please let me know how to deal with this issue. Thank you for any kind of help and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to track the state of your list.  I did this by extending the adapter and keeping a HashMap of all of the views in my adapter.  In my ListView, in onSaveInstanceState, I would get my adapter and iterate all of the views - for each view, I'd call onSaveInstanceState and store the result in my adapter's hashmap.  Then, during onRestoreInstanceState, I would iterate all of the views and invoke their onRestoreInstanceState method, passing them the state I'd saved.

This should result in solving both your data and your focus issue...

Good luck - happy coding.

B

Comment: Thank you for the help. Is it good to start with a Activity class with a list view control or is it good to start with a ListActivity for this list. Please let me know your idea. Thank you.

Comment: I think it really depends on your design goals and time constraints. A ListActivity is much faster to write than a ListView, however, you can reuse your ListView as many times as you'd like in other activities if needed. If you create list using a ListActivity it's going to lack reusability but will get done faster.  I typically err on the side of flexibility, but that's why all my code takes me longer and I often get accused of over-engineering :)

Answer (score 3):

Can do like This

```
ListView lw= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);
lw.setAdapter( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked ,value ) );
```